# Create column adding count of individuals as of monthly increments

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

[image: Pivot Chart]

I have census data I query from the database. Ultimately I will put his in a excel pivot chart. I am trying to take a count of the total individuals(case_num) based on their opened_date and have to total individuals count be shown by the last 6 months. In other words, what is the total census on the first of the month. The only thing I've been able to do is count and display the number of individuals who are new to the program based on the Month column.

[image: Census Data]

Below is the code I have written so far

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CEN') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE #CEN;
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CENX') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE #CENX;

SELECT CASE_NUM,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,CDASSIGN.UNIT_ID,SUB_UNIT_ID,CAUNIT.    [DESC],DATE_OPENED,DATE_CLOSED,SUBSTRING(CAST(DATE_OPENED AS NVARCHAR(30)),1,3) 
+ '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(DATE_OPENED AS NVARCHAR(30)),8,4) AS [DATE],
       SUBSTRING(CAST(DATE_OPENED AS NVARCHAR(30)),1,3) AS [MONTH],
       SUBSTRING(CAST(DATE_OPENED AS NVARCHAR(30)),7,5) AS [YEAR],

CASE WHEN DATE_CLOSED = '1753-01-01' THEN GETDATE()
WHEN DATE_CLOSED <> '1753-01-01' THEN DATE_CLOSED
END AS REAL_DATE_CLOSED,

CASE WHEN UNIT_ID IN (2802,2803) THEN 'QM'
    WHEN UNIT_ID = 2801 THEN 'Treatment'
    WHEN UNIT_ID = 3602 THEN 'Emer'
    WHEN UNIT_ID NOT IN (2801,2802,2803,3602) THEN [DESC]
    END AS [PROGRAM_NAME]

INTO #CEN
FROM CDASSIGN
INNER JOIN CDCLIENT ON CDASSIGN.CLIENT_ID = CDCLIENT.ID
INNER JOIN CAUNIT ON CAUNIT.ID = CDASSIGN.UNIT_ID
WHERE UNIT_ID IN (4141)
AND DATE_OPENED >= '1970-01-01'
AND DATE_CLOSED = '1753-01-01'
AND CDASSIGN.VOID_FLAG IS NULL
AND SUB_UNIT_ID IN (111)
ORDER BY CASE_NUM ASC

SELECT *, CONVERT(int,REAL_DATE_CLOSED) - CONVERT(INT,DATE_OPENED) AS     DAYS_IN_PROGRAM
INTO #CENX
FROM #CEN

SELECT CASE_NUM,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,UNIT_ID,SUB_UNIT_ID,    [DESC],DATE_OPENED,DATE_CLOSED,[MONTH],[YEAR],REAL_DATE_CLOSED,    [PROGRAM_NAME],DAYS_IN_PROGRAM
FROM #CENX
```

Comment: Show us what you have already tried and found to not work

Comment: Can you show some sample output?  Your instructions seem contradicting.  Also, why use a pivot table?  SQL is way more powerful than Excel IMHO.

Comment: I attached in the question what I have so far in a pivot chart. SQL is much better, unfortunately my manager requires Excel.

Comment: So is this a MSSQL question or Excel? Seems like you want an Excel formula? If so, please tag the question with Excel and remove the SQL tags. If it's TSQL you are in need of, please let us know what queries you have tried. Cheers!

Comment: It is TSQL and I added my code to my question.

Comment: Even with the example given, I think the question is a bit confusing. Do you want the count of CASE_NUM per DATE_OPENED? Or per month / 6 month / whatever? In the first case a simple count(*) group by date_opened should be sufficient!?

Comment: I did a count of the case_num. But my problem now is I have the Month on the X axis and it is only showing the count of case_num during that month. For example, if there were 5 case_num that had a date opened in the month of June, June on the x axis would only show 5 case_numbers. What I am trying to do is show the total count of all case_num from the beginning of time to June.